# Current limitation to capacitive voltage divider

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, capacitive

For an AC capacitive voltage divider, I would think the amount of current that could come from the divider would be limited by the absolute size of the capacitors. The flow of current should be a function of how much charge can be stored in each capacitor.

The only reference to such limitations i can find on Google is here: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/capacitive-voltage-divider-downsides.28895/. Ultimately the relevant commentary is a redirection to Wikipedia but I can't find anything pertinent there.

Given a capacitive voltage divider with an AC source, does the absolute size of the capacitors in the divider limit the current to the circuits attached to the divider¿ what is the relationship¿ (will kirchoffs laws predict this¿)

Comment: And what would your question be exactly?

Comment: Your question marks are upside down. Voltage drop across the capacitor will be U=C*di/dt. Differentiate and you end up with Ut=Ci. For AC input of grid frequency f, you end up with Udrop=C*i/(2*Pi*f).

Comment: Right and then do a sum of the voltage drops=0 around each divider with current summing laws and you have a system of equation. We would find that a relationship between the current/voltage in each divider... One of which would be to sum the current you derived with the current from the source... But it doesn't seem like that would provide a constraint on the current provided to the circuits attached to the voltage divider. Your derivation is for the current in the capacitors of the divider

Comment: Do you care about the worst-case instantaneous in-rush current, or only the steady-state AC current?